# static constexpr vs constexpr in function body?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

Is there any difference between `static constexpr` and `constexpr` when used inside a function's body?

```
int SomeClass::get(const bool b) 
{
    static constexpr int SOME_CONSTANT = 3;
    constexpr int SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT = 5;

    if(b)
        return SOME_CONSTANT;
    else
        return SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for any difference inside this function. Because, I guess that everything would be different if they were declared in a compile-time executed, _i.e._ `constexpr`, function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference between those two declarations is the lifetime of the objects. When writing the question, I thought that using `constexpr` instead of `const` would place that object into the `.rodata` section. But, I was wrong. The `constexpr` keyword, here, only provides that the object can be used at compile-time functions. So, the object is actually created in the stack during run-time and destroyed when leaving the function's body.
On the other hand, the `static constexpr` object is an object placed in the `.rodata` section. It is created at the first time we call the wrapping function. In addition, thanks to the `constexpr`, it is also available during compile-time.