# When is it better to use "static constexpr" than "constexpr"?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

In the answers to this question, ([static constexpr vs constexpr in function body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70711580)), it is stated that `static constexpr` puts the variable in the `.rodata` section, whereas `constexpr` alone may allow initialising the variable at run-time.

**IMPORTANT:** This questions is about static variables within a function, not to do with linking external libraries.

My question is: in what situation would we prefer one of these two to the other in the code, in practice? Can one be better than the other for some codes? It is very hard to imagine how this can happen. After all, with either options, we can write codes in exactly the same way, with the same computational result. And the compiler can presumably optimise to make the better choice. So what does the programmer need to judge when choosing?

Comment: Please read more about [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) and [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is not about linkage. It is within a function.

Comment: Please make your questions *self contained*. If it's based on another question, then yes link to that, but also please include examples and code and information inside the question itself.

Comment: `static` of a variable in a function is about **storage duration**.  `constexpr` is the object can be used at **compile-time**.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please read the question. I have described the meaning. It is very specific. It is self-contained. No need to read the other post to understand it. It makes no sense to include codes on this occasion - I have explained why.

Comment: @Eljay I mean, when they are combined, the words' original meaning no longer affect the result of computation - so that's why I am asking about such a subtle distinction. It is no longer helpful to look at the definition of `static` and `constexpr` separately.

Comment: C++ doesn't have `.rodata` sections. Your compiler might, but then you're asking about a particular tool chain, not about what `static` and `constexpr` mean in the C++ programming language.

Comment: *I mean, when they are combined, the words' original meaning no longer affect the result of computation*  In what way?  How are they different from when used independently or not at all?

Comment: @Eljay Not different, but more subtle.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "subtle" here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use a `constexpr` variable as an lvalue (i.e., you only read it's value but don't use it's address) then it's storage duration doesn't matter. The `static constexpr` variable and automatic `constexpr` variable are not odr-used (only their value is used), and will be optimized out. For instance, with GCC:

```cpp
int f(bool b) {
    int unused = 999;  // At -O1, this is optimized out
    constexpr int x = 123;  // At -O1, this is optimized out
    static constexpr int y = 456;  // At -O0, this is optimized out
    if (b) {
        return x;  // Replaced with "return 123;" at -O0 (x not actually used)
    } else {
        return y;  // Replaced with "return 456;" at -O0
    }
}
```

However, there is a difference when used as an lvalue. It can make your code wrong:

```cpp
const char* name(bool b) {
    static constexpr char name[2][6] = { "false", "true\0" };
    return name[b];  // Would be dangling if name was not `static`
}
```

Or it can have performance impacts:

```cpp
unsigned permute(unsigned i) {
    [[assume(i < 10)]];
    constexpr int table[10] = { 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 1, 9, 6, 0, 7 };
    return table[i];
}
```

Since `table` was not declared static, it will copy the initializer onto the stack and then index the stack. The initializer will be stored in the .rodata section. If `table` was static, `return table[i];` would just index into something in the .rodata section.

It looks like clang is smart enough to optimize this specific case (GCC isn't), but there will be differences if you want to pass a large constant block to a `void unknown_external_function(const void*);` (the compiler will be forced to copy onto the stack if the `constexpr` variable isn't `static).

It's hard to think of a situation where you would want to use an automatic `constexpr` variable over a `static constexpr` variable, other than pre-C++23 where `constexpr` functions can't declare `static constexpr` variables.